# How do get the cookies from the response in Micropython using urequests?

Tags: cookies, micropython

I use urequests to access a couchdb database from an esp8266 micro-controller.  I need to authenticate the session, and get a cookie back, that I can use in subsequent requests to the database.  It will also be used for longpolling the database for changes.

response.cookies
or
responce.headers

is not supported by urequests.  This all works in cPython, but not in Micropython.

Is there a way to access the raw response, or should I use another more complete library?

Comment: what about this? https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=8019 https://github.com/mardigras2020/urequests

Comment: I looked into this a bit as well and will concur with @Lixas. This is not included in the standard library. Look at his links and either use that updated library or use it as an example to parse out the cookies yourself.